# Solving nonhomogeneous linear recurrence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, homogeneous-equation

a.) nonhomogeneous linear recurrence(with constant relation) of degree 2.
The relation is:
$$x_n = x_{n-1} + 2x_{x-2} + 2n+1$$
Find the real number c and d such that $b_n = cn+d$ is a solution of this recurrence

$$b_n = b_{n-1} + b_{n-2} + 2n + 1$$
$$cn+d = c(n-1) + d + c(n-2) + d + 2n + 1$$
$$cn+d = cn -c + d + cn - 2c + d + 2n + 1$$
$$ 0 = (c+2)n + (d-3c+1) $$
$$ c = -2 , d = -7 $$

Is this correct?

b.) Show that $a_n$ is a solution associated homogenous recurrence:

$$a_n = a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2}, n\ge 2$$
 and $b_n$ is the particular soluction in part a).

for b) I have no idea how to do it

Comment: Oh no, without showing at least some of your own work, the question is recipe for disaster ...

Comment: What is $a_n$? Seems to be missing.

Comment: $a_n$ is under the b)